# Is C#'s Queue.dequeue() pass by reference or value?

Tags: c#, queue

So I'm trying to use Queues to create an object pool in order to recycle them. I seem to still get the same levels of memory usage after implementing it. I'm struggling to understand if using queue() or dequeue() is a pass by reference or value.

```
void ClearNodeListandBackupToPool(ref List<Node> nodelist)    
{    
    foreach (var node in nodelist)    
    {    
        nodePool.Enqueue(node);    
    }

    nodelist.Clear();    
}

Node CreateNewNode(Vector2 tile, Node parent, double gCost, double hCost)    
{    
    if (nodePool.Count > 0)    
        return nodePool.Dequeue().init(tile, parent, gCost, hCost);    

    return new Node(tile,parent,gCost,hCost);    
}
```

I expected that memory usage would be low or none with this method but it remained the same. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: With reference types, a reference is passed by value. With value types, the value is passed. `ref List<Node> nodelist` passes a reference to a reference, but that's irrelevant since you never assign to `nodelist` in the method. `ref` does nothing in that code. What does "the same levels of garbage" mean? Can you explain what the inputs are, what the desired output is, and what the *actual* output is?

Comment: What is `return nodePool.Dequeue().init(tile, parent, gCost, hCost);`? What's the intent of that? What does `init()` do, and why are you calling it on the item you take out of the queue?

Comment: List.Clear() will not reset capacity to 0, capacity remains unchanged,  so it may remain as garbage if GC will not collect it.

Comment: @michaelmena When you refer to "garbage levels", are you talking about memory usage?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry I mean when the garbage collection(GC) kicks in, it removes alot of objects(nodes). From my understanding, the GC removes objects from memory when there is no reference to them but in case I thought they should have a  reference  since I'm "storing" them into a queue.

Comment: @MichaelMena If there's a reference in the queue, there's a reference and they won't be garbage collected. I still don't have a good guess about what problem you're trying to solve. Please post a [minimal, correct, and verifiable code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue you're having, and describe the issue itself in complete, concrete, specific terms. What are the *inputs*, what is the *desired* program behavior, and what are you seeing *instead*? Also, again: What is `init()`? What does it do, why do you call it there?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry again.. .init() is just used as a fake constructor like new object(bah,bah). Kinda like a reset for the recycle. The function returns returns the node itself.

Comment: @EdPlunkett public Node init(Vector2 tile, Node parent, double gCost, double hCost)
        {
            this.tile = tile;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.gCost = gCost;
            this.hCost = hCost;
            this.fCost = this.gCost + this.hCost;

            return this;
        }

Comment: So your concern is simply that memory usage still goes up at runtime?

Comment: Yes. These objects are created very frequently so I would like to recycle them instead of re creating them.

Comment: Incidentally, it is not necessary to pass nodelist using `ref`.  The way you are using it does not require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Dequeue`, what is returned is a value which is a reference to the returned object. Before explaining what that means, it's easier to say why it probably doesn't matter to you:

If you do this:

```
var list = new List<Object>();
list.Add(new object());
var o = list[0];
```

There are now two references to the same object. `list` has one reference, and `o` has another reference. If `o` went out of scope but `list` didn't, then the object would not get garbage collected because there is still a reference to it.

If you do this:

```
var queue = new Queue<Object>();
queue.Enqueue(new object());
var o = queue.Dequeue();
```

There is only one reference to the object that was in the queue. Why? Because once you dequeue it, the item has been removed from the queue, so the queue no longer has a reference to it. `o` is the only reference, and if `o` goes out of scope the object can get garbage collected because there are no longer any references to it.

The question of whether the object is returned by value or by reference doesn't really matter.

What does it mean that the reference is returned by value?

In the above example using a list, `list[0]` returns a value which is a reference to the object. If we do this:

```
var list = new List<Object>();
list.Add(new object());
var o = list[0];
o = "x";
```

...`o` now refers to a string, but the item in the list has not changed. It has not been replaced with "x". That's because retrieving the item from the list returned a value, a copy of the reference to the object. We haven't retrieved the actual reference. So `o = "x";` replaces the copy of the reference returned from the list, not the actual reference contained in the list.

Others have observed - and I agree - that it's much easier to understand the behavior than it is to put it into words. The examples are easy to follow, but the description of what's happening isn't.

C# 7 introduced [`ref returns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values). This allows a method to return an object by reference. That means that the method returns its own reference. It's easy to spot because you would use the `ref` keyword when calling the method, like `ref var object = ref queue.Dequeue()`. (You can't do that because `Dequeue` doesn't use `ref returns`.)

I'm only including that because it seems necessary to literally answer your question. For practical purposes you probably don't care about it until you need it. I have no doubt that it was added for a reason but I haven't used it either.